# Emptying dynamically loaded span with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, scope

I have a dynamically loaded button that looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default admire"><span class="font awesome"> 3</span></button>
```

I am trying to empty the text value, in this case 3, and update it with a returned value from an AJAX call when the button is clicked. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "button.admire", function(){    
$.post('ajax/example.php', function(data){
$(this).find("span").empty();
$(this).find("span").append(data);
});
});
```

It is not working as expexcted. Is "this", the button, still referencable inside the ajax function? Or is it out of scope?

EDIT: How would I reference this span inside the ajax call function?

Thanks,

William

Comment: It must be out of scope because if I place that line before the ajax call function it will empty fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i understanding you clear try to do it like this, and don't forget to add class to btn

```
 $(document.body).on("click", "button.admire", function(){ 
   var btn = $(this);
 $.ajax({
   url : "your link",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "Json",//by default it's returning html
   data: "your data",// if you sending data
   async: "false", // it is mean, that until ajax request is not completed it not going forword
   complete: function (response) {

     btn.find("span").empty();
     btn.find("span").append(response.yourresponse);

   }

  })

 })
```

Comment: Would using the .post shorthand make me unable to access $(this) in the response function?

Comment: Figured it out, just needed to place $(this) in a variable to access it in the success function.

Comment: yes . declare the variable in global scope of click function like this- see my edit/ an very important to set async false in your case. with this, your function is not going forvard,until ajax request is not returned

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `this` was referring to the `$.post` callback function's `this` and not the button's `this`. You need to retain its reference by assigning it to a variable.

**Example:**

```
$(document.body).on("click", "button.admire", function(){  
  var span = $(this).find('span');
  $.post('ajax/example.php', function(data){
    span.empty();
    span.append(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, the typo was from sloppy partial copying and pasting. It does have this in reality.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to reference the button inside the AJAX function?